# Why sometimes error in async code makes the node.js server crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, error-handling, crash

I have read in some sites that in express.js 'Any uncaught errors in async code could crash the HTTP server causing DoS'.
I have made this example to check it, but I want to know why if the error occurs inside the express callback, the server does not crash but if it happens inside the setTimeout() function the server crashes.

Does not the error happen in async code in both examples, or one of them is not async and I am mistaken?
Why an uncaught error in some async code makes the server crash and in other async code doesn't?

```
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

http: app.get("/e1", (req, res, next) => {
  let p = req.query.p;
  let pn = parseInt(p, 10);

  //If the error happens here the server does not crashes
  let s = pn + y; // y does not exist, so an error occurs

  res.send("hi");
});

http: app.get("/e2", (req, res, next) => {
  let p = req.query.p;
  let pn = parseInt(p, 10);

  setTimeout(() => {
    //If the error happens here the server crashes
    let s = pn + y; // y does not exist, so an error occurs
  }, 100);

  res.send("hi");
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!");
});
```

Comment: Validate input and use try/catch

Comment: Does express handle the errors by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may become clear if we think of `throw` and `catch` operating on *the stack*:

`throw`: goes down the stack until it finds a handler, then continues from there.

`catch` adds an error handler to the stack.

For synchronous code, that could be visualized as:

```
 // Legend:
 -> function call
 <- function returns

 http.request -> express.handler -> [try] -> your function -> nested call -> Throw!
 <-            <-                   [catch] <-----------------------------------
```

Now when you start an asynchronous action, a callback will be called back somewhen, and that callback will end up on a new stack:

```
 // the current stack:
 http.request -> express.handler -> [try] -> your function -> start async action
 <-            <-                 <-       <-             <-

 // somewhen later, the timeout calls back
 timer -> your setTimeout callback -> nested call -> Throw!
 Crash! <-----------------------------------------------------
```

Now as Express attaches a `catch` handler to the callback into your code:

```
 Express.get = function(callback) {
   //...
   try {
     callback(req, res, next);
   } catch(error) {
    // handle error
   }
 };
```

that will handle errors, but just synchronous ones (it's simplified, the actual code is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/dc538f6e810bd462c98ee7e6aae24c64d4b1da93/lib/router/index.js#L404))

---

Now what should one do to handle that?

Basically: Wrap every callback into a promise (as that makes asynchronous error handling easier):

```
 const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

then `await` every promise you create, and wrap all that in a `try` / `catch`:

```
 app.get(async (req, res) => {
   try {
      await delay(2000);
      const p = q + d;
   } catch(error) {
     res.status(500).send("whoops");
  }
});
```

That works because `await` "keeps the stack" (but just the one of `async` functions that `await` on nested calls, thats why we need to add our own `try` / `catch` as Express does not `await` on the callback call), therefore an error inside of one of the nested `await` ed functions will fall back to our error handler.

```
 http.request -> express.handler -> [async] -> [try] -> nested call -> [await]
 <-                     <-               <-
 // synchronous code returned, the [async] stack will be kept
 [async] -> [try] -> nested call -> [await]

// somewhen, the promise resolves, execution coninues:
[async] -> [try] -> nested call -> Throw!
<-       <- [catch]  <--------------
```

Comment: So, you are saying that express route handling function callback is synchronous code? then, why is it called callback in express documentation?

Comment: @v8rs no, I'm not saying that.

Comment: I don't understand how express route handler catches the error

Comment: @v8rs with a `try { } catch(e) { }` block around the callback call

Comment: I still don't understand it, I am not using try catch blocks with express callbacks, but errors happening in express callbacks do not crash the app

Comment: @v8rs because express added one for you.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. You should make it clearer in your answer for future SO users that have this same doubt I had

Comment: @v8rs "Now if Express attaches a catch handler to the callback into your code" not sure how I could make that more clear ...

Comment: I understand it as 'Express could attach a catch handler but it doesn't attach it by default' due to the 'if' word, that confused me